# Ajax get request retrieves the JS file but fires error function with parsererror

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have a simple ajax GET request to request a JS file in my project as given below:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '{{assets}}/js/scripts.js',
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          success: function(result, status, jqXHR) {
            console.log("Success");
            },
          error: function(result, status, jqXHR) {
              console.log("in scripts error");
              console.log(result);
              console.log(status);
              console.log(jqXHR);
          }
      });
```

I am requesting it using AJAX because it has to be done after loading of some other library. But this ajax call fires error function intermittently. 2/7 times it'll result in error & rest of the times it will run as intended.

I am getting *parsererror* when it results in error. But still, the **scripts.js** file shows as loaded properly in Network tab even if the ajax call ends with an error.
[image: Network tab shows scripts.js]

Can someone please help me out with this? Really stuck.

Comment: Try using `$.getScript()` instead

Comment: or try adding dataType: "script"

Comment: @PrashantShirke I have tried adding that as well. Doesn't help. It's very weird that file appears to have loaded properly in the network tab though.

Comment: try adding dataType: 'jsonp',